# "Not Acceptable" error in Spring REST webservice on returning xml(produces="application/xml") response type

Tags: xml, spring, spring-rest

I am working on a webservice that should return json and xml (depending on user choice) to the user, I am using the simplest approach for this, that is to define two actions and change the (produces="") to whatever is required. I have defined the xml returning action as,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getToken", produces="application/xml", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Map<String,String> getToken(@RequestParam("username")String username, @RequestParam("password")String password)
```

this function is giving a "Not Acceptable" error upon hitting it, when I am trying this with,

```
produces="application/json"
```

it works fine. Can anyone please help?

Comment: The `produces` is part of the mapping, so if the client doesn't send an accept header of `application/xml` the method will not match and you will get a `Not Acceptable` as there is nothing that can handle the response.

Comment: You better not include `produces="application/xml"` in annotation, later you can check the header whether it is xml or json. By this way you can give user a choice to make either xml or json.